# Provide and inject multiple properties and multiple functions that mutates multiple properties

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-props

According to the Vue documentation on `provide` and `inject` APIs https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html, you provide a state and function to update state like this:

```
<!-- inside provider component -->
<script setup>
import { provide, ref } from 'vue'

const location = ref('North Pole')

function updateLocation() {
  location.value = 'South Pole'
}

provide('location', {
  location,
  updateLocation
})
</script>
```

Here it supposes that you have one property and the function will only mutate this property, but what if I have multiple properties and functions that mutate multiple properties at once:

```
<script setup>
import Header from "@/Components/Header.vue";
import Nav from "@/Components/Nav.vue";
import { ref, provide } from "vue";

const isNavClosed = ref(false);
const isHamburgerClosed = ref(false);
const isScroll = ref(false);

function toggleNav() {
    isNavClosed.value = !isNavClosed.value;
    isHamburgerClosed.value = !isHamburgerClosed.value;
}

function enterLeaveNav() {
    if (isHamburgerClosed.value) {
        isNavClosed.value = !isNavClosed.value;
    }
    isScroll.value = !isScroll.value;
}


</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <!-- Page Heading -->
        <header class="header container">
            <Header />
        </header>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row g-0">
                <nav
                    class="p-0 nav"
                    :class="[
                        isScroll ? 'overflowScroll' : 'overflowHidden',
                        isNavClosed ? 'width833' : 'width1633',
                    ]"
                    @mouseenter="enterLeaveNav"
                    @mouseleave="enterLeaveNav"
                >
                    <Nav />
                </nav>
                <main
                    class="ps-5"
                    :class="[
                        isNavClosed
                            ? 'offset-md-1 col-md-10'
                            : 'offset-md-2 col-md-9',
                    ]"
                    style="margin-top: 100px"
                >
                    <slot name="content" />
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

How can I provide all of these states and functions in one object, rather than providing every single property and function on its own, as all of them are related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your provide function that overrides the default vue `provide`. You could also not override, just rename, but I don't see much sense in keeping the default vue `provide` since the new function provides the same behavior:

```
import {provide as vueProvide} from 'vue';
export function provide(provides) {
    if (typeof provides === 'object') {
        for (const k in provides) {
            vueProvide(k, provides[k]);
        }
        return;
    }
    vueProvide(...arguments);
}
```

Usage:

```
provide({
  location,
  updateLocation
})
```